# Google Sheets Conditional formatting based on multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I had a spreadsheet in google sheets in my last company which highlighted all my rows based on my qualifying conditions. I can't remember what conditional formatting I used.

I have tried the `=IFAND` and `=AND` functions along with others.

This is what I am trying to do:

> If column B says DTC and the dates are between two ranges I want it
>   highlighted. Then I will have multiple rules that vary in dates and
>   words.

This is the last formula I tried.

```
=AND($B2="DTC",$E2>="10/1/2017",$E2<="10/6/2018")
```

Comment: If this is google-sheets then why the Excel tag?

Comment: I put google sheets but it said error and recommended excel so I changed it.

Comment: Scott Craner any ideas of the formula?

Comment: no, sorry, my expertise is in Excel and that formula should work in Excel.  The only suggestion I would make is to make sure the dates in Column E are actual dates and not text that looks like dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you enconclose dates between quotations marks they will be treated as strings, not as dates. Used [DATE(year,month,day)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969?hl=en) instead.

Comment: It looked like it was working until I added the second set of dates (end date).  =AND($B2="DTC",E$2>=DATE(2017,10,1),E$2<=DATE(2018,10,1))

Comment: @TiffanyPoche: Please create and share a demo spreadsheet including sample input and the expected result (a column with the resulting format applied manually)

Comment: [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15eJ7VQlvi4ejL6A7MWU3Rxupync0H5jYr7VwfA6bHh4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @TiffanyPoche : Did you applied the conditional formatting to the demo spreadsheet? I would like to see how do you applied it.

Comment: @TiffanyPoche Your data start on row 1 but your formula looks on the row below. Replace $B2 by $B1 and so on.

Comment: Since you are using relative references, the demo spreadsheet should use the same structure, in other words, if you have one header row in your real spreadsheet, add a header row in your demos spreadsheet. Columns / Cells that are not used for the conditional formatting formula could be blanks, only the cells used on the conditional formatting formula should contain values similar to the real spreadsheet just to check that the formula works fine.

Comment: That worked for the demo but not for my original spreadsheet. I am not sure why I copied the exact formula. Which in my real sheet the data starts on row 2 but I tried it both ways. It also didn't include one that had the word DTC along with something else. I want it to still include that. I know in other functions I put "*DTC*" but that didn't work for this formula.

Comment: Okay I fixed the demo sheet and the formula is working but still not in my original spreadsheet. I am copying and pasting the code. =AND($B2="DTC",E$2>=DATE(2017,10,1),E$2<=DATE(2018,10,1))

Comment: @TiffanyPoche : Do you mean that it fail on row 12 where B12 has `DTC - DCL` as value?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, row 12. But then on my original spreadsheet the whole formula is still not producing any results when I use this formula.

Comment: @TiffanyPoche The problem is that your formula use `=` and `DTC - DCL` is not equal to `DTC`. Please post a new question.