# Google Sheets Custom conditional formatting multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I made a spreadsheet in google sheets in my last company which highlighted all my rows based on my qualifying conditions. I can't remember what conditional formatting I used.

I have tried the =IFAND and =AND functions along with others.

This is what I am trying to do:

If column B says DTC, even if something else is also in cell, and the dates are between two ranges I want it highlighted. Then I will have multiple rules that vary in dates and words. I have attached a new demo sheet to help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yX_Ohfdz0uRKvOB8hvOpcO2sb5dSaAP6Zw-aR_HzK2E/edit?usp=sharing

The formula I have in there now is =AND($B2="DTC",E$2>=DATE(2017,10,1),E$2<=DATE(2018,10,1))

Comment: This is almost the same question as [Google Sheets Conditional formatting based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48099563/1595451). You should said that it's a follow up question and that you need that the formula works also for cell containing DTC along with other characters.

Comment: It is, but the formula is still not working. I copied and pasted the new demo spreadsheet which has the exact code. You told me to ask a new question so that is what I did. I was originally going to edit the other one. This demo sheet is the exact copy of the one I am working on with the extra information taken out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find both DTC and DTC-DCL with a wildcard try using if with search like this:

=if(and(search("DTC*",$B2),$E2>=date(2017,10,1),$E2<=date(2018,10,1)),"true","false")